# How to expose Svelte application using Apache2/IP address?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, apache-http-server

Help , I have svelte application running on localhost on port 5000 with backend express running on port 3000, and postgresql as database on port 5432.

I tried modifying /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf, installing and configuring nginx to expose running application to internet, based on research on available tutorial via googling, but not yet succeeded

I need the app to run like http://168.xx.xx.xx:5000 as example , I already shared my ssh key to my boss for accessing my apps

please help/any hint, i'm using ubuntu 18.04 :)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

> I need the app to run like `http://168.xx.xx.xx:5000` as an example.

If your application is already running on port `5000`, then the simplest solution may be to just forward incoming requests to `168.xx.xx.xx` on port `5000` to whatever local machine is running the application. Obviously, you would need to make certain port `5000` wasn't blocked from external requests on the local machine by e.g. routing or firewalls, but direct IP access often doesn't need a reverse proxy setup (which is what you appear to be trying to implement).